# Hot to put a image as a background in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a image as an background. I believe the follwing code is right, but it does not work. Please anyone help me. My image is inside the folder images which is in the same directory as index.html.

```
body{
    background-image:('images/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

In a previous project I had the following: This code works, but the code above doesn't. I can not understand why

```
body{
background-color:white;
color:#404040;
font-size:11pt;
font-family:Georgia, Garamond, serif;
background-image:url("images/silverware.jpg");
background-repeat:repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Comment: `My image is inside the folder images which is in the same directory as index.html.` - but is it in the same directory as your **stylesheet** ?

Comment: background-image:url("images/silverware.jpg"); in second and  background-image:('images/background.jpg'); in first...are you missing  'url'?

Comment: Oops, overlooked the `url` parameter ;)

Comment: Damm it, what a idiot. Thanks guys

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The image url is relative to the css file not to your html file. So if your file structure looks like this:

folder

-css

-images

-js

-index.html

then you will need to add ../ to your background-image url. In this case it would look like this:

```
body{
    background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

***edit : actually the missing url part of the background image property is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

It is not working because you left out the url prefix in the background image property:

```
body{
    background-image:('images/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

It should be:

```
body{
    background-image:url('images/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Comment: you could mention in comments.

Comment: @user3830694 I could, but this is the answer to his question. If it was a comment it might be overlooked not just by the OP, but by others who have the same question later.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in your second code sample. Missing the 'url' parameter

```
background-image:url('images/background.jpg');
```

Also make sure, your image path is correct

Comment: you could mention in comments.

Comment: @user3830694 Why this obsession with mentioning things in comments? As the missing url keyword was the answer to the OPs question, an answer is the most appropriate/correct place for this.